# Socket.io java client connects to server but doesn't emit

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've been struggling with this for a few days now. I am trying to connect my Android client to a Node.js server on my localhost. The server prints "connected" when the Android client connects, but no other messages get through.

Android client:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userObj = parseUserObj();

        if (numPlayers.equals("2")) {
            try {
                socket = IO.socket("http://10.0.2.2:3700/multiplayer");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
            socket.on("start", start);
            socket.on("endGame", endGame);
            socket.on("message", message);
            socket.on("getLetterSet", getLetterSet);
            socket.connect();
            socket.emit("joinGame", userObj);

        }
        populate();
        startTimer();



    }

private Emitter.Listener message = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    try {
                        updateMessageBox(data.getString("message"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    };
    private Emitter.Listener endGame = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    try {
                        String tie = data.getString("tie");
                        String winner = data.getString("winner");
                        String loser = data.getString("loser");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    private Emitter.Listener start = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    start();

                }
            });
        }
    };
    private Emitter.Listener getLetterSet = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];

                    try {
                        MainActivity.LETTERSET = (String[]) data.get("letters");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        return;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Node.js Server:

```
module.exports = function (io) {

    var waitingClient = null;
    var scores = [];
    var User = require('../models/user');
    var winner, loser, tie;
    var Bot = require('../bot/bot');

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
        console.log("connected");
        client.on('disconnect', function() {
            if (waitingClient == client) 
                waitingClient = null;
        });

        client.on('score', function (score) {
console.log("score received");
            if (typeof client.partner == 'function') {
            client.partner.emit('message', {message: client.username + "'s score: " + score});
           }
        });

        client.on('submitScores', function (data) {
            scores.push(data);
            if (client.partner.lifeForm) {
                scores.push({score: client.partner.score,
                             username: client.partner.username});
                client.partner.endGame = true;
            }

            if (scores.length == 2) {
                if (scores[0].score > scores[1].score) {
                    winner = scores[0];
                    loser = scores[1];
                    tie = null;
                 } else {
                    winner = scores[1];
                    loser = scores[0];
                    tie = null;
                }
                if (scores[0].score == scores[1].score) {
                    tie = true;
                };

                scores = [];

                // save the results of the game to the players' user objects in db
                if (winner !== loser) {
                User.findOne({ "username": winner.username}, function (err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            if (!tie) {
                            user.wins += 1;
                            user.save(function (err) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                            });
                        } else {
                            user.draw += 1
                        };
                    };

                });

                User.findOne({ "username": loser.username}, function (err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            if (!tie) {
                            user.losses += 1;
                            user.save(function (err) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                            }); 
                        } else {
                            user.draw += 1;
                        };

                };
            });
            };

            client.emit('endGame', {winner: winner, loser: loser, tie: tie});

            // test if the player's partner is a bot. If not,
            // emit end of game results.
            if (typeof client.partner.emit === 'function') {
            client.partner.emit('endGame', {winner: winner, loser: loser, tie: tie});
            };
        }

            });


        // client.on('toRoom', function (room, event, msg) {
        //  io.to(room).emit(event, msg);
        // });

        client.on('joinGame', function (user) {
            console.log("Player Joined!" + user);

            // if there is a player waiting for an opponent, join his game
            if (waitingClient && waitingClient != client) {
                client.partner = waitingClient;
                waitingClient.partner = client;

                client.username = user.username;
                client.emit('message', {message: "You have joined a game with " + waitingClient.username + "!"})
                client.partner.emit('getLetterSet', waitingClient.letters);
                client.emit('getLetterSet', waitingClient.letters);
                client.partner.emit('message', {message: user.username + " has joined the game!"});
                client.emit('start');
                client.partner.emit('start');
                waitingClient = null;


            } else {
                // else, set the client as waitingClient
                client.emit('message', {message: "Waiting for opponent..."});
                waitingClient = client;
                waitingClient.username = user.username;
                // store player one's letterset so both players 
                // use the same letterset 
                if (user.letters) {
                waitingClient.letters = user.letters;
                } else {
                    client.emit('getLetterSet');
                }

                // ***test bot functionality***
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var botPlayer = new Bot.BotPlayer(waitingClient); 
                    client.partner = botPlayer;
                    client.emit('message', {message: "You have joined a game with " + botPlayer.username + "!"})
                    client.emit('start');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    botPlayer.play();
                    }, 4000);

                    waitingClient = null;
                    }, Bot.getRandomInt(5000, 15000));

                };
        });

        client.on('toPartner', function (event, msg) {
            client.partner.emit(event, msg);
        });
    });


}
```

Comment: try calling ```socket.emit("joinGame", userObj);``` after the ```Socket.EVENT_CONNECT``` event

Comment: But socket.emit is called directly after socket.connect()